# MATLAB: fast large-sigma smoothing of 2d images

Tags: matlab, image-processing, blur, gaussian, smoothing

I have a program that processes large sets of 2d greyscale images and currently uses imgaussfilt() several times in the processing of each image (Matlab 2015b). This is proving to be very costly as far as run-time. I have a few instances of larger sigma values which seem to be more costly (i.e. imgaussfilt(image,[1,40])...imgaussfilt(image,[10,15])).

Does anyone know of any faster versions/methods for gaussian smoothing?

I have tried using the FFT/IFFT method but this seems to take considerably longer than the native MATLAB imgaussfilt() feature.

Have also tried running gaussian smoothing on the X and then Y dimension successively but this takes slightly longer than the native imgaussfilt() feature.

A different smoothing method may work fine also, are there any other methods that are considerably faster? (tried imboxfilt()...only slightly faster and not as good).

thanks in advance

Comment: Have you tried using `imfilter` with a Gaussian kernel? `imfilter` uses the Intel Integrated Performance Primitives for efficient filtering.

Comment: Why do you need to apply this filter "several times" in the processing of one image? maybe you can use it only once at the start with the appropriate size

Comment: @rayryeng I tried imfilter with a gaussian kernel-was pretty fast but still slightly slower than the imgaussfilt()

Comment: @amitay I am doing different processing steps/pulling out different characteristics from the same image (I can trim away a few of the imgaussfilts and am working on that as well but most of them are necessary for my purposes)

Comment: Maybe try to do some of the processing using a smaller images? using pyramids?

Comment: Does downsizing the image hurt your results? If you have to do numerous passes w/ different filter settings, even a small size reduction might give you the desired speed up.

Comment: Thanks for all the replies, resizing the image did the trick and my results still look pretty good..not sure why I didn't think of it, thanks for the simple fix!

Answer (score 1):

From your description it seems, you are using highly anisotropic filters, here [1,40] or [10,15]. If this is really the case,  so that each of your filters is unrelated to the other, I recommend to use image averaging by use of integral images. The relevant matlab functions are integralimage and integralfilter. This is not Gaussian smoothing but instead it's a box filter. However, once calculated for the input image, the integral image can be reused for many different filterings, and the strength of filter effect is independent of the kernel size (!), which is probably not the case with imgaussfilter. However,  maybe you should take care for effects at the image borders.

Comment: By choosing the right size of the box filter, you can approximate the effects of a Gaussian blur. Nice observation with suggesting the box filter. +1.

Answer (score 0):

One of the cheapest smoothing methods I can think of is to simply take the average of neighbouring pixels:

```
A(i,j) = (A(i-1,j) + A(i+1,j) + A(i,j-1) + A(i,j+1) + w*A(i,j))/(4+w);
```

where `w=4` is some weighting factor of your choice. You can shift the array with circshift:

```
A(i-1,j) = circshift(A(i,j), [1 0]);
```

and so assuming that you store all `N` of your images in an array `A(x,y,N)`, the full Matlab command is:

```
A = (w*A + circshift(A, [-1 0 0]) + circshift(A, [1 0 0]) + circshift(A, [0 -1 0]) + circshift(A, [0 1 0]))/(4+w);
```